# Need help with regression output

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients

I am pretty confused right now. This is my homework, I need to find the missing values (coefficients, standard errors, r, and r squared)  only using the regression result. I went over my textbook a few times, but couldn't figure it out. Can someone please help me start how to do this. Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: You need to add the self-study tag.

Comment: Did it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could start with the fact that dividing a regression coefficient by its standard error gives you the t-statistic. Such division essentially transforms your regression coefficient into its respective value in the t-distribution. Then, for each regression coefficient, you may find its respective p-value (i.e. its level of statistical significance) by using this [online caluclator](http://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/tdistribution.aspx). For each regression coefficient, you need to enter its respective t-value. You also need to provide the residual degrees of freedom value. It is calculated in the following way: 
`df = N - k - 1 = 2404 - 6 -1 = 2397` in your case. Note, `N` is your sample size; `k` is the number of independent variables, and `-1` is an extra degree of freedom you lose for calculating the intercept.

You may find beneficial to check [this explanation](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/output/regression-analysis-2/) of the OLS regression analysis output, published by the UCLA Institute of Reseach and Digital Education.